# Xamarin forms - Style in android

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, colors

I've implemented dark mode support recently in my Xamarin app following this tutorial : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/modernizing-ios-apps-dark-mode-xamarin/

I've set my Label Colors using a Style defined in App.xaml like this :

```
<Style x:Key="label" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor"  Value="{DynamicResource label}"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="labelLight" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource labelLight}"/>
</Style>
```

Where the colors `label` and `labelLight` are defined in a `ResourceDictionary` named LightTheme.xaml and DarkTheme.xaml.

I also implemented a custom renderer for iOS like this:

```
public class ThemeRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            return;

        SetTheme();
    }

    public override void TraitCollectionDidChange(UITraitCollection previousTraitCollection)
    {
        base.TraitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection);

        if (TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle)
            SetTheme();
    }

    private void SetTheme()
    {
        if (TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle == UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark)
        {
            App.Current.Resources = new DarkTheme();
            App.AppTheme = Theme.Dark;
        }
        else
        {
            App.Current.Resources = new LightTheme();
            App.AppTheme = Theme.Light;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I get in trouble, my Android version of the App doesn't recognize these colors (everything is in LightGray) and my App doesn't run anymore under iOS 12 and lower. I have no clue what to do to fix this.

Comment: In android,did you update your base theme to use `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight` ?And in ios,it seems to support dark model after ios 13.

Comment: I didn't updated my base theme, could you maybe help me doing it ?

Comment: And I need to set OS target to 13.0 in my info.plist ?

Comment: Could it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example in android activity

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher =true)]
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity{

   ...
 }
```

then in your **Resources/values/styles.xml** :

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"> // base theme to use Theme.AppCompat.DayNight
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ff29b6f6</item> 
</style>
```

and you could read [this](https://intelliabb.com/2019/11/02/how-to-support-dark-mode-in-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: Seems like the article you linked is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot.